# How to loop through rows of specific columns and input into new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a large data frame containing many rows and columns. I would like to loop through >100 columns of data, for which not every cell is filled.

Eg. Rows = Group of participants in a game Columns 12-251 = Name of individual participants

Each group may have differing number of participants ie there may be empty cells if the group has less than 100 participants.

How do I loop through the data frame, to find the last participant from each group and create a column that copies the last participant's name?

I need to loop the data to find 'NaN' cell, but how do I then copy the cell before that and copy it to a new column?

My attempt:

```
last_player=[]

for i in range(len(Game)):       
  player = Game.iloc[i, ac]    #iterate over these columns of players name; ac is a list of columns
  for x in range(len(player)):
    if player != 'NaN':
      continue
    else: 
      last_player.append(player[x-1]) 
      break

Game["last_player"]=last_player
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
   1329         raise ValueError(
-> 1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1332         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your `Game` dataframe?

Comment: It sounds like last_valid_index after transposing the dataframe could spot the player in question. Including a sample of the dataframe would be very helpful